# 2 errors java flops converter

Tags: java, converters

I've got 2 errors:

```
C:\Users\anderson\Documents\FlopstoGFlopsConverter1.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
       long flops = Long.parseLong(this.textField1.getText());
                                       ^
  symbol: variable textField1
C:\Users\anderson\Documents\FlopstoGFlopsConverter1.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
       this.textField2.setText(String.valueOf(gFlops));
           ^
  symbol: variable textField2
2 errors
```

it's just so difficult to learn.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class FlopstoGFlopsConverter1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    FlopstoGFlopsConverter1() {
        setSize(500, 350);
        setVisible(true);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Convert!");
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        this.add(panel);
        button1.setBounds(190, 230, 100, 30);


        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Enter Flops");
        panel.add(label1);
        this.add(panel);
        label1.setBounds(89, 52, 150, 50);

        JTextField textArea1 = new JTextField(20);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        panel.add(textArea1);

        this.add(panel);
        textArea1.setBounds(160, 69, 160, 20);


        JTextField textArea2 = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(textArea2);
        this.add(panel);
        textArea2.setBounds(159, 155, 160, 20);


        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Gigaflops ");
        panel.add(label2);
        this.add(panel);
        label2.setBounds(91, 150, 200, 30);



    }


    public static  void main(String[]args) {
        new  FlopstoGFlopsConverter1();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("");

        try {
            long flops = Long.parseLong(this.textField1.getText());

            double gFlops = flops/1000000000;


            this.textField2.setText(String.valueOf(gFlops));
        } catch(Exception exception) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `textArea1` and `textArea2` as instance variables and use those in `actionPerformed()` method.

Currently, there are no `textField1` and `textField2` declared, instead `textArea1` and `textArea2`, but even these are in the local scope of the constructor.

```
JTextField textArea1 = null; // Outside the constructor, inside the class
JTextField textArea2 = null; // Outside the constructor, inside the class
...
...
// Inside actionPerformed method
long flops = Long.parseLong(this.textArea1.getText()); // use textArea1
...
this.textArea2.setText(String.valueOf(gFlops));
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says you do not have any declaration of textField1 and textField2. Declare them first. If you meant to use textArea1 and textArea2, declare them as instance variables after the class declaration so you can use them. Your class would look like this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class FlopstoGFlopsConverter1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField textArea1;
    private JTextField textArea2;

    FlopstoGFlopsConverter1() {

        setSize(500, 350);
        setVisible(true);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Convert!");
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        this.add(panel);
        button1.setBounds(190, 230, 100, 30);


        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Enter Flops");
        panel.add(label1);
        this.add(panel);
        label1.setBounds(89, 52, 150, 50);

        textArea1 = new JTextField(20);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        panel.add(textArea1);

        this.add(panel);
        textArea1.setBounds(160, 69, 160, 20);



        textArea2 = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(textArea2);
        this.add(panel);
        textArea2.setBounds(159, 155, 160, 20);


        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Gigaflops ");
        panel.add(label2);
        this.add(panel);
        label2.setBounds(91, 150, 200, 30);
    }


    public static  void main(String[]args) {
        new  FlopstoGFlopsConverter1();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("");
        try {
            long flops = Long.parseLong(this.textArea1.getText());

            double gFlops = flops/1000000000;


            this.textArea2.setText(String.valueOf(gFlops));
        } catch(Exception exception) {

        }
    }
}
```